# How to Flatten and get expected output shown below from pig after Group by

Tags: hadoop, bigdata, apache-pig, etl, flatten

Sample Date:

ID       marks       date

12345     12     20210204

12345     13     20210204

12345     2      20210204

Input:

(12345,{(12345,12,20210204),(12345,13,20210204),(12345,2,20210204)})

Output needed:

(12345,27,20210204)

Second element is the aggregated value.

Help is Appreciated

Answer (score 0):

```
output = FOREACH input GENERATE
    group AS ID,
    SUM(sample.marks) AS mark_sum,
    MIN(sample.date) AS first_date;
```

You may need to tweak based on your relation and field names. You might also want to group by the date field too if these are all the same.